# AxiomSoapMessageCreationException: Unknown content type 'application/wsdl+xml'

Tags: java, spring-ws, axiom

Anyone have any idea what the following Exception might mean?

I can't find "wsdl+xml" anywhere in our project, not sure where its coming from?

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageCreationException: Unknown content type 'application/wsdl+xml'
at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory.getSoapEnvelopeNamespace(AxiomSoapMessageFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory.createAxiomSoapMessage(AxiomSoapMessageFactory.java:247)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(AxiomSoapMessageFactory.java:218)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:86)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:553)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:502)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:351)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:341)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the server side:

> AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:86)

Ideally it would be better, if you will persuade the server team to change the `content-type` header, although you may try to intercept the response from the `WebServiceConnection` implementation.

However you might send the wrong request, e.g. not to the service URL, but WSDL.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, you're bang on, sending request to the WSDL URI rather than the service URL. Stupid mistake, thanks!